# How to be more productive developing a browser game in javascript+jquery+css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm working on a browser game for facebook/orkut. The graphics and the JSON data have been given to me. My work is to organize the information received in the JSON on the screen. To do this I use css+jquery+javascript (most of the time jquery). I'm not as productive as I'd like to be. My development enviroment is:

1. eclipse
2. firefox
3. firebug with cssUpdater and other firebug plugins

I still have to make every little thing by hand (barebone) programming. For example, to make a screen, I have to make the divs, work the css, and then put it to jquery. This process takes one day to make just one screen workable. I want to know if there is some way to be more productive, such as with a tool to help with the css positioning and updates. Or something to help with the debug process more than firebug does. I tried coffescript, but I don't have the time to learn it right now, and my enviroment is Windows. I see that coffescript works better in linux, but my real problem is css positioning/debugging.

tnx for help.

Answer (score 3):

1. [gameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/) is a jQuery plug-in to help make javascript game development easier by adding some simple game-related classes. [this is your best bet]
2. Also have a look at [these plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/game) that show you some cool ways to make games in jquery
3. Also some really good tips [here](http://www.slideshare.net/pbakaus/building-a-game-engine-with-jquery)
4. Here is another [experimental library for 3d stuff](http://collusioni.st/projects/axonome)

Send us link when you are done so we can kill some time on your games ;)